# How to find who depends on specific artifact in gradle?

Tags: gradle, transitive-dependency

In our composite project someone depends on asm-4 and asm-3 transitively.

I would like to know who bring these transitive dependencies to the project.

Is there any way to draw a graph of dependencies or somehow find who depends on asm-3/asm-4

Note: asm dependency is a buildSrc/buildScript dependency, not the build's process itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd into `buildSrc`, then run `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration runtime --dependency asm`.

Answer (score 1):

Type `gradle dependencies` to see the whole graph. It's also possible to exclude dependencies. Search for [Excluding transitive dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Comment: Yeah, I know about this task. This is exactly what I need. But it does not work on buildSrc project. Project 'buildSrc' not found in root project.

Comment: No idea how to display `dependencies` for `buildSrc` unfortunately. But I suppose that dependencies exclusion works exactly same.

Comment: Can You please post a sample project with dir structure?